# VBA Skip File if Partial String Not found in Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, string, conditional-statements, partial

What's the most efficient way to search for a partial string in a worksheet?

I'm trying to search for "N   " in C4 through the end of column C of the active sheet. If "N   " does not appear in the array then I want to close the file. If "N   " does appear I want to print a message saying "Force data found"

I know you could use the countif function, sum up the times it appears, and then use if/then to determine action -- but I imagine there's a better way. Thoughts?

My code below does a search for "N    " in the worksheet and then deletes the rows where it is not present. **Note: I want to include the 3 spaces after the N in the search**

[Image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmv2w.png)

```
Sub InspectColumn()
'Define variables
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim Res As Variant

' Define LastRow as the last row of data based on column C
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' Sets check range as C1 to the last row of C
Set cRange = Range("C1:C" & LastRow)

' For each cell in the check range, working from the bottom upwards
For x = cRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    ' find if 'N   ' found in any cell in the row
    Res = Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & x & ":" & x & ", ""*N   *"")")
    
    ' if 'N   ' not found delete row
    If Res = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Delete
    End If
    
Next x
```

End Sub

Comment: Use a filter and delete?

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines.  I've put in as an answer, but will need some tweaking.

```
Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*N*"
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Columns("A:A").AutoFilter
```